# Gnuplot Multi-branch fit

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file 'file.dat'. Because it's short, I'll say it contains the following data

```
x     y1(x)      y2(x)
0     -41.2462   -41.1297
0.1   -42.6114   -39.7339
0.2   -43.7644   -38.2653
0.3   -45.0846   -36.8728
0.4   -46.2912   -35.4905
0.5   -47.3873   -34.1428
0.6   -48.3437   -32.8365
```

The functions y1(x) and y2(x) are supposed to be quadratic functions of the form

```
y1(x) = a - b*x + c*x^2,
y2(x) = a + b*x + c*x^2.
```

The only difference between the two is that the linear term b is inverted in the second equation (essentially they're a parabola and it's reflection across the y axis).

I'm trying to do a multi-branch fit. To make it easier, the variable a is a known constant, it's supposed to represent the point where they intersect at x=0. Due to some small error, they don't quite match up so I'm taking a to be defined as

```
a =  (y1(0) + y2(0))/2 = (-41.2462 - 41.1297)/2 = -41.1879.
```

So I've defined my gnuplot functions as

```
y1(x) = -41.1879 - b*x + c*x**2
y2(x) = -41.1879 + b*x + c*x**2
```

For the fit function, I've tried

```
f(x,y) = (y==0) ? y1(x):y2(x)
fit f(x,y) 'file.dat' using 1:2:3 via b, c
```

This gave me the values of

```
b = 14.8708
c = -1.57747
```

which yields this [plot of file.dat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDk0X.png).

The upper branch of the fit looks pretty close, but the lower branch dips way below at higher values of x. I'm hoping to find values of b and c that closely approximate both y1(x) and y2(x) simultaneously. I can eyeball it myself, but I've got 800 such similar files to work through, and I'm hoping to automate this process with a c++ script later.

I think I'm missing some important step, or have gotten some syntax wrong somewhere. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I don't think you can do a multi-branch fit if there are multiple data points in the same line in your data file. Note that the examples in `help fit multi`use either the dataline number or the datafile index to distinguish between the branches; with your current file format you would have to distinguish them by the column number (and consider each line twice!) which I don't think is possible. You might have to change the format of your data file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reformat your data file so that each line contains only a single data point. For example, if you write it like

```
# y1 dataset
0     -41.2462
0.1   -42.6114
0.2   -43.7644
0.3   -45.0846
0.4   -46.2912
0.5   -47.3873
0.6   -48.3437

# y2 dataset (separated by a single blank line)
0     -41.1297
0.1   -39.7339
0.2   -38.2653
0.3   -36.8728
0.4   -35.4905
0.5   -34.1428
0.6   -32.8365
```

then you can use the following gnuplot script:

```
set key left
a = -41.1879
y1(x) = a - b*x + c*x**2
y2(x) = a + b*x + c*x**2

f(x,y) = (y == 0 ? y1(x) : y2(x))
fit f(x,y) "file.dat" u 1:-1:2 via b,c

plot y1(x), y2(x), "file.dat" u 1:2 w p
```

It uses the pseudocolumn `-1` to separate the two data sets in the `fit` command.

[image]